# Python not closing file, Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, jupyter-notebook

Reading a .csv file in Jupyter:

```
filename = "myfile.csv"
start_pd = time.time()
try:
    with open (filename, 'rb') as file:
        reader = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=10000, error_bad_lines=False, header=None)
        df = pd.concat([x for x in reader], ignore_index=True)
        df.columns = dfcolslist
        file.close #also tried reader.close() and file.closed
    print("{} read successfully in {:.2f} secs".format(filename, time.time() - start_pd))
except IOError:
    print("could not read {}".format(filename))
```

cmd error message:

```
> ren "myfile.csv" "date_myfile.csv"
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

GUI error message:

```
The action cannot be completed because the file is open in Python
```

Comment: You are not supposed to call `close` when using `with open...`

Comment: commenting out the close line doesn't change anything, problem persists

Comment: So your problem is not with "closing the file" as the title suggests

Comment: the error messages are saying it's 'open' or 'being used by another process' i.e. not closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing a string to `pd.read_csv` it tries to open an already opened file.

Its [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) says

> filepath_or_buffer : str, path object, or file-like object Any valid
>   string path is acceptable. The string could be a URL. Valid URL
>   schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file. For file URLs, a host is
>   expected. A local file could be: file://localhost/path/to/table.csv.
>
> If you want to pass in a path object, pandas accepts either
>   pathlib.Path or py._path.local.LocalPath.
>
> By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as
>   a file handler (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO.

Either:

- Pass the file name as string to `pd.read_csv` and let it handle opening, reading and closing the file on its own:

  ```
  reader = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=10000, error_bad_lines=False, header=None)
  ```
- **Or,** open the file yourself using `with open` and pass the file object to `pd.read_csv`:

  ```
  with open (filename, 'rb') as file:
      reader = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=10000, error_bad_lines=False, header=None)
  ```

In either case you are not supposed to call `.close()` on your own.